# Windows 10 Batch file to change directory names and move directories

Tags: windows-10, batch-rename, wildcards

I have fifty directories, in pairs, with names such as:

```
ABC123-aaa-X0001  
ABC123-bbb-X0001  
XYZ456-aaa-X0001  
XYZ456-bbb-X0001  
SDF543-aaa-X0001  
SDF543-bbb-X0001
```

I want to remove all the "-aaa-X0001" parts of the names to end up with the following:

```
ABC123  
ABC123-bbb-X0001  
XYZ456  
XYZ456-bbb-X0001  
SDF543  
SDF543-bbb-X0001
```

I then want to move the **"-bbb-X0001"** directories into the corresponding renamed directories, to end up with:

```
ABC123  
XYZ456  
SDF543
```

These would each therefore contain the original contents of the corresponding **"-aaa-X0001**" directory, plus the corresponding **"-bbb-X0001"** directory as a sub-directory.

I would like this all to be done using a batch file.

To rename the directories, I first tried using the **`REN`** command:

```
REN *-aaa-X0001 *
```

I soon discovered that wildcards don't work with directory names.

I then tried using the **`MOVE`** command:

```
MOVE *-aaa-X0001 *
```

This doesn't work either.

I also tried various ideas based on:

```
for /d "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-"
```

But I couldn't get anywhere with this.

I have spent several hours getting nowhere, so am I hoping someone can help!

Thanks.

Comment: You say "batch", but PowerShell is the default console & best way to automate precesses such as this in Windows 10. Were you simply unaware of this or opposed to PowerShell?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Keith. I don't have much experience with batch files, and have even less (none!) with PowerShell, so I was hoping to be able to achieve this apparently quite simple task without learning something new. Happily I have since received a solution that works perfectly in this situation, and is close to what I had already been messing around with. I will however look into PowerShell too as it will likely be useful in the future. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I

> 1. remove all the "-aaa-X0001" parts of the names
> 2. move the "-bbb-X0001" directories into the corresponding renamed directories

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d') do (
  if [%%b]==[aaa] (
    ren %%a-%%b-%%c %%a
    )
  if [%%b]==[bbb] (
    move %%a-%%b-%%c %%a
    )
  )
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test\test>dir /b/s
F:\test\test\ABC123-aaa-X0001
F:\test\test\ABC123-bbb-X0001
F:\test\test\XYZ456-aaa-X0001
F:\test\test\XYZ456-bbb-X0001
F:\test\test\SDF543-aaa-X0001
F:\test\test\SDF543-bbb-X0001
F:\test\test\test.cmd

F:\test\test>test
        1 dir(s) moved.
        1 dir(s) moved.
        1 dir(s) moved.
F:\test\test>dir /b/s
F:\test\test\test.cmd
F:\test\test\ABC123
F:\test\test\XYZ456
F:\test\test\SDF543
F:\test\test\ABC123\ABC123-bbb-X0001
F:\test\test\XYZ456\XYZ456-bbb-X0001
F:\test\test\SDF543\SDF543-bbb-X0001

F:\test\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [For /f - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Move - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)
- [Ren - Rename - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)

Comment: That's perfect David! Thanks very much. I had got close in my various attempts at using tokens and delims, but missed a couple of key bits. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Renaming files from command line we saw how to rename files using Rename command.   We can use Rename command to rename directories too. See the syntax below.

Rename  dir_oldname  dir_newname
Example:

G:\data>mkdir dir1
G:\data>dir /b
dir1
G:\data>rename dir1 dir2
G:\data>dir /b
dir2
G:\data>
Note that, with rename command, we can’t move the files to another drive or directory. This command just renames the existing file/folder and does not create a new file.  That is why it does not accept full path for the target file name. If you try to do that you will get the error – “The syntax of the command is incorrect.”

Example:

C:\docs>ren 1.txt c:\docs\2.txt
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
The below rename command works fine.

C:\docs>ren c:\docs\1.txt 2.txt
C:\docs>dir /b
2.txt
We can also use ren (the short form of rename) for rename operations.  Both Ren and Rename refer to the same command.

This command can be used to rename files or directories on all Windows OS editions i.e Windows 2000, XP, Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b /a:d "*-*-*"')do >nul (
     if not "!_dir!" == "" move /y "%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c" "!_dir!"
     set "_dir=" <nul || set "_dir=%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c"
    )

for /f tokens^=1-3^delims^=^- %%a in ('dir /b /a:d "*-*-*"')do >nul (
     move /y "%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c" "%%~fa"
    )

endlocal && goto :EOF
```

[image]

For your fifty or more directories, with a predictable name layout, this bat/cmd code can automate the task, so that no editing is necessary.

Therefore, you do not need to add all known folder names to any **`if`** conditions in your **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file.

**1)** Use a **`for /f`** loop to list all folders with the layout target delimited by **`-`** and using the **`1-2-3`** tokens, and **`%%~a-%%~b-%%~c`** has become the same for your folder name layout **`SDF543-bbb-X0001`**

```bat
for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=^- %%a in ('dir /on/b/a:d *-*-*')do
```

- **Obs.:** List your folders by **name order**: **`/on`**

**2)** You can use **`if not`** to check if any values ​​(previous/last listed folder) are defined in the variable **`_dir`**, if the condition is true, the current folder will be moved to the last path to previous folder name defined in the **`_dir`** variable, and this will occur only if the path and part of name match the current variable **`%~fa`**

```bat
if not "!_dir!" == "" move /y "%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c" "!_dir!"
```

**3)** The next command is something that does not make sense to me, that is, I have no idea how it works, even if theoretically it shouldn't work, but in fact it works...

```bat
set "_dir=" <nul || set "_dir=%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c"
```

**4)** Add a second for loop to rename folders as desired, removing **`-%%~b-%%~c`** from the names

```bat
move /y "%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c" "%%~fa"
```

---

## About mechanic in item **3**

I admit that I don't understand how it can work, and I lack the knowledge to explain what is done here, sorry for this, and the theory is some like:

```bat
rem :: Command              ::  Explanation

set "_dir=" <nul            ::  remove _dir variable/value

set "_dir=" <nul ||         :: if _dir variable was not removed by set "_dir=" <nul
                            :: the next command will by executed 
                            :: this "||" is called "operator" 

set "_dir=%%~fa-%%~b-%%~c"  :: if _dir variable was not removed, set the string 
                            :: below to the value for the _dir variable:
                            :: %%~fa-%%~b-%%~c is the same to drive:\path\name_folder
```

The command **`set "_dir =" <null`** always seems to be executed, the operator **`||`** should never execute the command **`set "_dir = %%~fa-%%~b-%%~c"`**,
but using variables with delayed expansion enable, it may be the explanation that makes this work.

---

**For command line help, you can use `/?`:**

```bat
set /?, Ren /?, For /?, Dir /?, Setlocal /?, Endlocal /?, Goto /?, if /?, RMDir /?, RD /?
```

**On the internet, you can get more help on:**

- **[Set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[Ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**
- **[Dir](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)**
- **[RD / RMDir](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)**
- **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Goto :EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**
- **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)**
- **[If, Else If, Else, If Defined, Errorlevel ...](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && | & operators...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution. Thanks too for editing my original post. I'll keep those formatting styles in mind next time I post a question!

Comment: @JDR This is an entertainment for me these days, thank you too, good question. ..